# How to show the value for a field of a variable based on the order of the field?

Tags: julia

I am a beginner in Julia. I have a variable called myvariable. It has 3 field: sum, minus, product. If I want to see the value of sum, I can input myvariable.sum. If I want to see the value of minus, I can input myvariable.minus. My question is that, if I only know the order of the field,for example, I know sum is the first field, minus is the second field, product is the third field, how can I get the value of the field based on the order? I tried myvariable.1, myvariable.2, myvariable.3, it didn't work.

Comment: I just want to extract the numeric value in the second field while I don't know the name of the second field.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
getfield(myvariable, 1)
```

to get the first field.

Also note that you can find a name of the field number `1` if you write:

```
fieldname(typeof(myvariable), 1)
```

As an additional comment note that `myvariable.minus` does not necessarily give you a field `minus` from your variable. It gets you a **property** (which does not have to be the same).

If you want to access property number `1` from you variable write:

```
getproperty(myvariable, propertynames(myvariable)[1])
```

Comment: My actual problem is a little more complex. The problem is that getfield(myvariable, 1) returns ?. I am running Julia under linux system, the first field names cannot be displayed, it's ?.  In windows system, it can be displayed as σ. How can I deal with it? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I guess that is an issue with your font and it's support for Unicode symbols, luckily there are many other fonts with better support for it, than the one you are currently using. Which font are you using on Linux?

Comment: I have fixed this problem by using Putty instead of SSH Secure Shell Client.

Comment: In general Unifont is best to recommend from my experience.